# Animate background image of a :after element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Having this code:

```
#header .banner { background-color:#000; height:270px; }
#header .banner:after { content: ""; background:url(/images/header_1.jpg) center center; width:100%; min-width: 1024px; height:270px; margin: auto; display: block;}
```

I need to make a transition of the /images/header_1.jpg to other image, using javascript (jquery) or css3.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, if you want the image alternating back and forth. The easiest way involves using setInterval combined with JQuery's .css feature.

```
var state = 0;
function start(){
    setInterval(function(){
        if(state=0){
            state = 1;
            $("header").css("background","url(/images/header_1.jpg)")
        } else {
            state = 0;
            $("header").css("background","url(/images/header_2.jpg)")
        }
    },1000);
}

start();
```

1000 represents the time in milliseconds before the change happens.

You can also simply convert the image to an animated png.

Comment: If you don't want the image alternating back and forth, you could also just make the setInterval function include a clearInterval, in order to do it once then stop.

Comment: the problem here isn't how to do the javascript, but how to change the :after css element. Look that the background is not in the #header .banner, but in his :after element.